# Why does my program print 0 instead of the calculated sine?

Tags: c, cs50

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float sine(float a, float b);

int main()
{
    printf ("Choose an option:\n1- Sin\n2-Cos\n3-Tan\n");
    int option = get_int();
    if (option==1)
    {
        printf("What is the hypotnuse of the triangle?\n");
        float hypotnuse = get_float();
        printf("What is the opposite side of the triangle?\n");
        float opposite = get_float();
        sine(opposite, hypotnuse);
        printf ("The answer is %f", sine);

    }   
    // else … cosine, tangent
}

float sine(float a, float b)
{
  return a/b;
}
```

Whatever value I provide for `hypotnuse` and `opposite`, the output I get is `0.000000`. Please explain what's wrong with the code?

Comment: please provide sample inputs you are trying

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) then **use the debugger `gdb`** (learning how to use a debugger is a required skill, even from beginners)

Comment: does this not give compile error?

Comment: Please update the title so it meaningfully describes your problem, for the benefit of others with the same problem. "Why isn't my program working?" could be the title of pretty much any question on this site.

Comment: Oh trust me, I tried to title the post meaningfully but I couldn't come up with the appropriate words.

Answer (score 6):

`sine` is the address of the function `sine()`.

You must use the return value of the function `sine()`:

```
float result = sine(opposite, hypotnuse);
printf("The answer is %f\n", result);
```

There are different ways to do this in C, an other example that consume the result "on the fly" like jonathan-leffler propose:

```
printf("sine(%f, %f) = %f\n", opposite, hypotnuse, sine(opposite, hypotnuse));
```

This is working because the result of the call to the function `sine()` is send directly to `printf()` as an argument.

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much for clearing that up for me.

Comment: Or: `printf("The answer is %f\n", sine(opposite, hypotnuse));` — or, even better because it echoes the input and explains what it is doing — `printf("sine(%f, %f) = %f\n", opposite, hypotnuse, sine(opposite, hypotnuse));`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I wanted to explicit how to get the return value of a function because I think that this is what confuse the OP because he/her is always saw `foo(bar());` example.

Comment: Using the explicit `result` is OK; it's also possible to consume the result on the fly (hence 'or').  And the 'print explanation' is a good idea whether you're working with a result variable or not.  (And at some point, I need to get a dig in about 'hypotenuse', but I know you're using what the OP used.)